# OpenGraph story appears in Activity Log but not on Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My OpenGraph story does show up in the Activity log but not on Timeline.
I did enabled Explicit Share additional capability.
The app is in development mode.
How do I guarantee the actions do appear in Timeline?

Comment: Not all stories shows up on Timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to enabling "Explicit Share" in the app settings I had to add

```
.putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true)
```

when building my `Action`.

Comment: The app settings toggle just says that "my app is capable of explicitly sharing", you need to add the property in the actions that you create to indicate that the user actually *meant* to share this explicitly. Also be sure that the user does expect this, because otherwise you'd be violating FB's platform policies.